# how to click on second link with same name while cucumber testing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber

This is my view file ....... and i want to click at ..........

```
<a class="pull-left width_100" style="font-weight:bold; color:black" href="/service/partner/97">Company name 4</a>
```

u can check my view code ....

```
%ul.pull-left.unstyled.width_100
- @servi<div id="search_data_4">
  <div class="data pull-left" style="width:100%;border-top:1px solid black;border-bottom:1px solid black;margin-top:60px;position:relative;">
  <div class="pagination" style="color: black; top: -100px;" outer_windows="0">
    <ul class="pull-left unstyled width_100">
      <li class="pull-left" style="background-color: #F1F1F1;margin-bottom: 10px;margin-left: 6px;padding: 8px;width: 750px;">
         <ul class="unstyled pull-left" style="width:32%">
            <li class="pull-left width_100">
               <a class="pull-left width_100" style="font-weight:bold; color:black" href="/service/partner/97">Company name 4</a>
               <span class="pull-left width_100">Street No. 4</span>
               <span class="pull-left width_100">zip code 4, city 4, Antigua and Barbuda</span>
```

and i have write step defination

```
When /^I press on any service partner$/ do
  page.driver.browser.execute_script %Q{ $('#search_data_4 ul li ul:eq(0) li a').trigger("mouseenter").click(); }
end
```

but this step will not run as i want to click on that link. let me know

Comment: Cucumber itself does not drive browsers. What gem are you using to drive the browser (eg capybara, selenium-webdriver, watir, etc.)?

Comment: I am using webdriver to run at browser.

Comment: and let me know one more thing that on hover at menu section then list will appear and how can write this thing with cucumber as well as display at browser while test should running.